# Determine singular primes of quadratic ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I have to determine all singular primes of the quadratic ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$, where $d$ is a non-square integer, but it is not necessarily squarefree.

Say $d=p_1^{k_1}\ldots p_t^{k_t}$, with at least one $k_i=1$ (since then $d$ is not a square). Also, let $f=X^2-d$ be the monic polynomial. I know that I have to check when the determinant is equal to zero mod $p$, because for these primes $p$, we could have a problem of a multiple factor. Since $\Delta=4d$, we see that $p=2$ gives a problem, as well as all primes $p_i$ dividing $d$. From this, I'm getting a bit stuck. I think that for $f$ to be reducible, we have to look at the primes $p_i$ for which $p_i^2|d$ (Eisenstein). But when do I know for which $p$ the function $f=X^2-d$ is completely ramified?

Comment: With singular primes, do you mean ramified primes? If so, then it is precisely enough to look at the primes dividing the discriminant. Namely, a prime is ramified if and only if it divides the discriminant.

Comment: @Dedalus With singular I mean non-invertible. I'm trying to check this with Kummer-Dedekind theorem

Comment: Let me see if I understand correctly: You want to work with $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}],$ not the integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})?$

Comment: @Dedalus Yes, that's true

Comment: If so, in a Dedekind domain, all non-zero ideals are invertible, so the only case for you to look at is when $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ is not a Dedekind domain. This happens precisely when this is not the integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d}).$ This is not the full ring of integers precisely when $d \equiv 1 mod 4,$ so all prime ideals are invertible except when $d \equiv 1 mod 4.$ There will still however be primes that *ramify*

Comment: @Dedalus I know that this is true for $d$ squarefree, but how can I prove that that's also true if $d$ is not necessarily squarefree?

Comment: The same proof works fine.

Comment: @Dedalus I'm sorry, but the proof I know uses the fact that $d$ is squarefree, since the remainder of division by remainder cannot lie in $p^2\mathbb{Z}[X]$ since $d$ is squarefree..

Comment: You are referring to the proof of the fact that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ is the integral closure when $d \equiv 2,3 mod 4?$ If so, this contains a proof of that fact: http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/210BPage/handouts/quadint.pdf But I recommend first trying to work it out for yourself.

Comment: The restriction to squarefree $d$ is not a restriction.

Comment: Since if say $d= b^2d',$ then $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d}) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d'}).$ So you can still get something from the case where there is a square, by dividing out until' you have something that is square-free.